# Hide some events from specific user on Google Calendar

Tags: php, zend-framework, permissions, google-calendar-api, acl

Is it possible to hide some events on a shared Google Calendar from a specific user?

Here's an example of what I want:

```
Calendar Shared with 2 other persons: Person A and Person B.
I add an Event named Event 1.
Me and Person A should see it but Person B should not.
I add an Event named Event 2.
Me and Person B should see it but Person A should not.
```

I read somewhere that Google Calendar have ACL's but, can they be used per event?

Currently, I'm using `Zend_Gdata_Calendar` to display all my events.

Based on the correct answer, I managed to add **attendees** using this with `Zend_Gdata_Calendar`:

```
$who[0] = $service->newWho();
$who[0]->setEmail("theemail@gmail.com");
$who[0]->setValueString("Person Name");
$stat = $service->newAttendeeStatus();
$stat->setValue('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.accepted');
$who[0]->setAttendeeStatus($stat);
$event->setWho($who);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Google's [help article](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/34580?hl=en) on how private vs. public events work. Assuming you wanted to create the event visible to you and person A you should be able to:

1. Give person A and B read (or at most editor) access to the calendar.
2. Create the [event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) programatically and set the `visibility` attribute to `private`
3. Add person A as an `attendee` during the event creation.
4. You and person A should be able to see all event details.
5. Person B should be able to see the time as booked but not see event details.